# How do I control two 240v water pumps with float switches connected to one outlet pipe so that only one pump is switched on at a time

Tags: relay, solid-state-relay

The pumps are in two different 1m deep wells that collect rain water to stop flooding they have float switches but because they use the same discharge pipe if both pumps tried to pump at the same time it would take a long time to lower the level. Need a relay to only allow one pump to operate at a time.

Comment: First you have to create a de-confliction rule in words.  It may make sense to include fairness over time. It may even be you actually need to measure the level and not just use a float switch.  Does allowing both to run at once actually take longer than having them take turns when both are needed?  Does it overheat them?

Comment: So if one pump is running and the other well overflows, is that ok? As you don’t seem to consider that.

Comment: Why does using two pumps take longer than using one pump?

Comment: This sounds a bit like a contrived homework problem ...

Comment: You can use build some relay logic. Simple solution can make another problem,  like Solar Mike mentioned.

Comment: I will try and clarify. Firstly it’s not home work project. At present I have one pump that discharges through a 32mm pipe which is not ideal but to run a bigger pipe is not possible. Another area nearby floods so I have put a second pump in a well but I can only connect this to to the existing 32mm pipe. Each pump has a non return valve and I thought having a box with some sort of relay to only let one pump at a time be on. It would not cut the pump out time but would cut the time each pump was on.